# Django, adding two foreign keys to the same model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table which relates one row in the Context table to another row in the Context table.
In Django I try to add two foreign keys and it says I need to use related name. I've been reading the documentation on related name but I cannot understand it. I include the working model below with commented out rows. Following I also include the template. Can anyone fix the code below?

model.py

```
class Relationship (models.Model):
    relationship_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # context_id1 = models.IntegerField()
    context_id1 = models.ForeignKey(Context, db_column='context_id1', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    context_id2 = models.IntegerField()
    # context_id2 = models.ForeignKey(Context, db_column='context_id2', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True, null=True)
```

template

```
  {% for relationship in context.relationship_set.all %}
      Current Context:{{relationship.context_id1.number}} <br> # works
      Relationship:{{relationship.relationship}} <br> # works
      Related Context: {{relationship.context_id2.number}} # fails
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The `related_name` is the name of your relation "in reverse". So from a `Context` to a `Relationship`. Since you here target the same model twice, the two can not be named both `relationship_set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is the name of your relation "in reverse". So from a `Context` to a `Relationship`. Since you here target the same model twice, the two can not be named both `relationship_set`. You thus can give these different `related_name`s. For example:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_name='relationship_id')
    context1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Context,
        db_column='context_id1',
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
        related_name='relations_through1'
    )
    context1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Context,
        db_column='context_id1',
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
        related_name='relations_through2'
    )
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True, null=True)
```

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
>   will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
>   be `context1`, instead of <s>`context_id1`</s>.

Comment: I should really add that I know in normal circumstances you don't add the _id suffix, but Django is set not to manage that because it's going on top of a pre-existing database structure.

Comment: @SpatialDigger: well you specify the name of the column of the *database* with `db_column`. So you can specify `db_column='context_id1'`, but at the Django level, the field should still be `context1` (if you follow the conventions).

Comment: yeah, I'm coming from the database side, so I'm not conforming to Django's ways of doing things. I'm now looking at how to retrieve the data in the template through this related name.

Comment: ah got it, replace relationship_set with relations_through1